# Replacing character within string

Tags: c, char, string-literals

This is a very basic question, it has been asked alot, but all of the examples I have looked at have been slightly different

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    char title[] = "HELLO!";
    title[1] = "F";

    printf("%s", title);

}
```

Why does this cause the following error -

```
jdoodle.c:6:14: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     title[1] = "F";
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

`"F"` is a string literal. It has type `char[2]` (that is it is a character array containing a string) and is presented in memory like

```
char unnamed_literal[] = { 'F', '\0' };
```

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 6 In translation phase 7, **a byte or code of value zero is appended**
>   to each multibyte character sequence that results from a string
>   literal or literals.78) **The multibyte character sequence is then
>   used to initialize an array of static storage duration and length just
>   sufficient to contain the sequence.** For character string literals,
>   the array elements have type char, and are initialized with the
>   individual bytes of the multibyte character sequence...

For example try to execute this statement

```
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( "F" ) );
```

In this expression statement

```
title[1] = "F";
```

the left operand has type `char` while the right operand that has the type `char[2]` is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element that is it has type `char *`.

From the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, **an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object** and is not an lvalue. If the array
>   object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

So in this statement

> jdoodle.c:6:14: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without
>   a cast

that is there is an attempt to assign the address of the first character of the string literal to a character that does not make sense.

It is evident that you mean assigning the character constant `'F'` to the object `title[1]` of the type `char`.

That is you mean the following statement

```
title[1] = 'F';
```

You could use the string literal but you need its first character instead of its address. You could write for example

```
title[1] = "F"[0];
```

or

```
title[1] = *"F";
```

or even like

```
title[1] = 0["F"];
```

But of course it is better and simpler just to use the character constant instead of the string literal

```
title[1] = 'F';
```